# How to fetch react-cookies if CORS is blocking it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, fetch-api

I'm using `react-cookies` and I want to fetch it from client side to server side. The problem is when I print the request in `NodeJS` I don't see any cookies neither in `header` nor anywhere else. I'm not sure if the cookies weren't sent.

I've read I can't fetch cookies automatically and I need to add `{credentials:'include'}` or `{credentials:'same-origin'}`. I've tried them both and didn't get errors. I've read that it could be connected with `CORS` policy.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    // credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
       body: JSON.stringify(user)
});
```

Could you please tell me how to check if the `cookies` were sent and if so  where exactly to find the `cookies` or if it didn't send the cookies how to fix it.

Comment: what framework do you use? `express.js`?

Comment: @marzelin yes, I use express.js

Comment: Have you tried to enable cors: https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b ?

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz yes, it is enabled this way ```app.use(cors('*'));```

Comment: you have to enable CORS Pre-Flight. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: @marzelin ```const cors = require('cors'); app.use(cors('*'));```  I'm sure that CORS is enabled, and maybe it blockes the cookies. I tried the way you've suggested: ```app.options('*', cors())``` but I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To allow CORS requests with credentials, you have to make express do 2 things:

- send `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header with the value that matches `window.origin` (it cannot be a wildcard `'*'`)
- send `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'` header with the value of `'true'`

Both can be done by passing options object to `cors`:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
}))
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question. How can I check if the cookies were sent? At the moment I'm working on a log-in page. Is there a way to check if there's a cookie in the request or not?

Comment: @Seda put `console.log(request.headers.cookie)` in route handler

Comment: @Seda most probably you haven't set any cookies. How do you set cookies?

Comment: I've tried these both options: ```{credentials: 'include'}, {credentials: 'same-origin'}```. This is how I set cookies. I didn't see any other way, please tell me if there's one

Comment: @Seda that's how you send cookies (you should use `{credentials: 'include'}`). But how do you set cookies for that external domain? with `document.cookie`?

Comment: ```import cookie from 'react-cookies'
cookie.save(cookiName, cookie, { path: '/' });``` 
I set them like this

Comment: @Seda then you are creating cookies in origin A and sending request to origin B. Cookies created on origin A are only send to origin A. You can't send it to origin B. You have to create cookies on origin B to have it logged on origin B.

Comment: To be honest I don't imagine how to do that. Could you please briefly explain it or send a good source to read as I didn't find a proper one.

Comment: @Seda one way is to create endpoint on your server like `/set-cookie`. The endpoint will be setting cookies passed to it in a query like `/set-cookie?cookieName=cookieValue`. In express you can set cookies with `res.cookie`